# Compiling ember-data

Tags: ember.js, bundler, ember-data

In the [Read-Me for ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/README.md) I found the following lines:

> **Getting ember-data:**
>   Currently you must build ember-data.js yourself.
>   Clone the repository, run `bundle` then `rake dist`. You'll find 
>   ember-data.js in the `dist` directory."

I'm a little confused though... what does "run bundle" mean?

Comment: It means you have to install a flippin' distribution of Ruby and assorted Ruby tools in order to build your JavaScript. (why no I'm not super annoyed at this inconvenience at all why do you ask?)

Answer (score 6):

It's a ruby thing. Bundler is a rubygem for managing application dependencies. The bundle command is used to install all of the rubygems that are required by the ember-data project. Try this:

```
git clone git://github.com/emberjs/data.git
cd data
bundle install
rake
```

If bundle command is missing, you'll need to install the bundler gem:

`gem install bundler`

Of course you also need to have a modern version of ruby and rubygems ;-)

See http://gembundler.com/ for more info on bundler

Answer (score 1):

`run bundle` means install the package dependencies via [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) which will read the `Gemfile` and install the dependencies defined in it.

To install the dependencies run the command `bundle install`